# set column order of fields using CSOM/REST javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, column, spfield

I am creting list fields using **CSOM** ecma script. How do I set the **column order** of the fields to be displayed in the form programmatically?
For eg: I have created the following fields programmatically :

```
Title, Description, Property
```

I have to change the order in which it has to be displayed in the form programmatically to

```
Property, Title, Description
```

How do I set this property?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I wrote a Chrome Extension using my answer for reordering columns. Thank you again as I got the idea from you. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reorder-list-columns/fmmkacoijdknmnjjphlhjccioediljlp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[FieldLinkCollection.Reorder()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlinkcollection.reorder(v=office.15).aspx) can reorder fields in list forms. Followings are the steps of reordering fields.

1. Find the list
2. Find `ContentType`
3. Find `FieldLinks` of the `ContentType`
4. Reorder columns of `FieldLinks`

`Reorder()` takes an array of Internal Names of the fields. Based on the order of this array,   `Reorder()` method reorders the fields in list forms.

## Example

In my **Tender List**, I am going to reorder `Title` and `Tender Number` fields.

[image]

Using **CSOM** **C#** :

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tender List");
ContentTypeCollection contentTypeColl = list.ContentTypes;

clientContext.Load(contentTypeColl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var itemContenType = contentTypeColl[0];
var itemContenTypeFieldLink = itemContenType.FieldLinks;

string[] filedOrder = {
    "Tender_x0020_Number",
    "Title"
};
itemContenTypeFieldLink.Reorder(filedOrder);
itemContenType.Update(false);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

In my previous forms, The order was `Title`, `Tender Number`. Now it is

[image]

**Using JSOM**

```
var listContentTypes;

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tender List');

listContentTypes = list.get_contentTypes();

ctx.load(listContentTypes);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(get_contentTypes_success, onFailure);

function get_contentTypes_success() {
    var itemContenType = listContentTypes.getItemAtIndex(0);
    var itemContenTypeFieldLink = itemContenType.get_fieldLinks();
    itemContenTypeFieldLink.reorder(['Tender_x0020_Number', 'Title']);
    itemContenType.update(false);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(field_reorder_success, onFailure);
}

function onFailure(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}

function field_reorder_success() {
    console.log("done");
}
```

## Chrome Extension

Finally, I wrote a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reorder-list-columns/fmmkacoijdknmnjjphlhjccioediljlp) to reorder list/library columns. It is open source. You are always welcome for suggestion and contribution.

https://github.com/dipongkor/reorder-rolumns

Comment: How would you do this for simpler lists that do not have content types enabled? I just want to reorder columns on the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change field order in view then check below scenario.

I had two different lists and similar view. I wanted to update destination list view field order if user change order in source view.

```
ViewFieldCollection srcViewFields = srcView.ViewFields;
ViewFieldCollection destViewFields = destView.ViewFields;

var srcArray = srcViewFields.ToArray<string>();
var destArray = destViewFields.ToArray<string>();

foreach (var item in destArray)
{
    destViewFields.MoveFieldTo(item, Array.IndexOf(srcArray, item));
    destView.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the question but in case if you want to modify the status of the column ("Hidden","Required"), the below code is useful ([Link](http://www.roelbagao.com/2016/09/26/hide-columns-of-content-type/))

```
string[] ContentTypeColumnNames = new string[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" };
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourSiteAddress"))
{

    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testdoclib");
    context.Load(list);
    var x = context.LoadQuery(list.ContentTypes.Where(ct => ct.Name == "Document"));
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    ContentType ctx = (ContentType)x.FirstOrDefault();
    context.Load(ctx);
    context.Load(ctx.Fields);
    context.Load(ctx.FieldLinks);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (FieldLink f in ctx.FieldLinks)
    {
        if (ContentTypeColumnNames.Contains(f.Name))
        {
            f.Hidden = true;
            ctx.Update(false);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
    context.Load(ctx);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```